RP2040, reconciling ownership and glitchy hardware
I have some Rust code for an RP2040.  It communicates over UART, but I'm dealing with some sorta glitchy components; seems like after a few milliseconds of inactivity they need a few microseconds of activity on the tx line before they've warmed up and actually accept tx, which means my UART communications (past a limited baud) get garbled.
I'd like to try toggling the tx line shortly before the UART transmission, to warm up the components, but I pass ownership of the pin to the UART, and I don't know how to get it back or bypass it or circumvent the problem.
Here's sorta what I'd like to do, but of course the borrow checker doesn't like it, as commented:
let mut gpio0 = pins.gpio0;
let mut gpio1 = pins.gpio1;
let uart_pins_0 = (
    gpio0.into_function(), // `gpio0` moved due to this method call
    gpio1.into_function(),
);
let mut uart0 = UartPeripheral::new(peripherals.UART0, uart_pins_0, &mut peripherals.RESETS)
    .enable(
        UartConfig::new(baud.Hz(), DataBits::Eight, None, StopBits::One),
        clocks.peripheral_clock.freq(),
    ).unwrap();
gpio0.into_push_pull_output().set_high().unwrap(); // use of moved value: `gpio0`
delay.delay_us(10);
gpio0.into_push_pull_output().set_low().unwrap();
delay.delay_us(10);
uart0.write_str("test\n").unwrap();

How do I accommodate my buggy components while working with the borrow checker?

Since your hardware is already buggy and causes UB, you might as well lean into it and just create multiple mutable references (or multiple instances of the pins with ptr::read).

@cafce25 I don't actually know how to do that; I thought the borrow checker prevented multiple mutable references.  Is this a thing unsafe can do, or what?

Well that was only half serious, if your hardware is faulty there is not much sense in trying to get it to do what you want, replace it.

Not really an option, I'm afraid; I think it's just a property of the component involved, not a defective unit; seems like it expects data to be sent more continuously than it is.  Surely there's SOME way of circumventing the borrow checker, if there's not a way to play nice with it, here?  I guess I can just go google that specifically, if there's no better ways specific to the classes involved, here

UartPeripherals provides you a free() method that can give you the pins back.
In practice, this looks something like:
let (d, mut p) = uart1.free();
let mut g = p.0.into_push_pull_output();
g.set_low().unwrap();
delay.delay_us(3);
g.set_high().unwrap();
p.0 = g.into_function();
uart1 = UartPeripheral::new(d, p, &mut peripherals.RESETS)
.enable(
    UartConfig::new(baud.Hz(), DataBits::Eight, None, StopBits::One),
    clocks.peripheral_clock.freq(),
).unwrap();

Note that, according to testing, recreating the uart clears the rx queue.

Oh, nice; that fits what I was looking for, and I think it fixed my problem.  One concern - it seems like freeing and recreating the uart clears whatever rx queue it had (and seems to take ~24us), which means that transmitting may create a small gap where I can't receive anything.  I don't suppose there's a way of reenabling the uart without reinitializing it, or something?

@Erhannis Such constructor seems to not exist, unfortunately. You can file an issue or open an PR. I don't have enough knowledge of embedded to know if this constructor will have to be unsafe. In the meantime, you can patch rp2040-hal, or you can use hacky transmute(()) that is half unsound.

While the other answer is probably safer, I finally figured out how to toggle the pin without actually owning the pin reference.  I assimilated a bunch of macros and system functions etc. to replicate what it was doing under the hood.  It still seems to incur a small delay, ~2us, though I think the delay of the free/recreate mechanism was actually only ~12us, and ~12us of the apparent delay was part of the transmission process itself.  BUT, it doesn't reset the uart rx queue!  Here's my code, for those who come after.  Note that some of the code handles bank0 vs qspi bank stuff, and some just assumes bank0 because I think all the normal gpio pins are in bank0?
let num = gpio4_id.num; // gpio4.id(), back when you had access to it;
let mask = 1 << gpio4_id.num;
let bank = gpio4_id.bank;

// become push_pull
unsafe {
  let sio = &*pac::SIO::PTR;
  let gpio_oe_set = sio.gpio_oe_set();
  match bank {
      DynBankId::Bank0 => &gpio_oe_set,
      DynBankId::Qspi => core::mem::transmute(&sio.gpio_hi_oe_set()),
  }.write(|w| { w.gpio_oe_set().bits(mask) });
}
// next is: pin.pad_ctrl().modify(|_, w| w.ie().set_bit());
let gpio = unsafe { &*pac::PADS_BANK0::PTR };
gpio.gpio(usize::from(num)).modify(|_, w| w.ie().set_bit());
// next is: pin.io_ctrl().modify(|_, w| w.funcsel().variant(funcsel));
let gpio = unsafe { &*pac::IO_BANK0::PTR };
let io_ctrl = &gpio.gpio(usize::from(num)).gpio_ctrl();
io_ctrl.modify(|_, w| w.funcsel().variant(pac::io_bank0::gpio::gpio_ctrl::FUNCSEL_A::SIO));

// set_low
unsafe {
  let sio = &*pac::SIO::PTR;
  let gpio_out_clr = sio.gpio_out_clr();
  match bank {
      DynBankId::Bank0 => &gpio_out_clr,
      DynBankId::Qspi => core::mem::transmute(&sio.gpio_hi_out_clr()),
  }.write(|w| { w.gpio_out_clr().bits(mask) });
}

delay.delay_us(3); // How long to hold the spike

// set_high
unsafe {
  let sio = &*pac::SIO::PTR;
  let gpio_out_set = sio.gpio_out_set();
  match bank {
      DynBankId::Bank0 => &gpio_out_set,
      DynBankId::Qspi => core::mem::transmute(&sio.gpio_hi_out_set()),
  }.write(|w| { w.gpio_out_set().bits(mask) });
}

// become uart
// next is: pin.pad_ctrl().modify(|_, w| w.ie().set_bit());
let gpio = unsafe { &*pac::PADS_BANK0::PTR };
gpio.gpio(usize::from(num)).modify(|_, w| w.ie().set_bit());
// next is: pin.io_ctrl().modify(|_, w| w.funcsel().variant(funcsel));
let gpio = unsafe { &*pac::IO_BANK0::PTR };
let io_ctrl = &gpio.gpio(usize::from(num)).gpio_ctrl();
io_ctrl.modify(|_, w| w.funcsel().variant(pac::io_bank0::gpio::gpio_ctrl::FUNCSEL_A::UART));

The key to one of my problems was that there are registers that need set, for each of the following operations: become push/pull, set low, set high, become uart.
